# How to show adobe pdf documents in Windows SharePoint Services 3.0

Tags: wss-3.0, 2007, pdf

I would like to create a list (document library) with pdf documents and when i choose one document it opens up in webpart on same page (like a preview option), or if that's not possible to open up in browser instead of launching Adobe Acrobat or showing 'Save As' button.

Is that possible ?

Answer (score 1):

This should be doable using a DVWP and some code underneath to infer the filepath.  You can use this code to embed .pdf's into the browser:

```
    <object data="myfile.pdf" type="application/pdf" width="100%" height="100%">

  <p>It appears you don't have a PDF plugin for this browser.
  No biggie... you can <a href="myfile.pdf">click here to
  download the PDF file.</a></p>

</object>
```

If you need help, let me know.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways of doing this.
You can build a webpart that list the content of your list and got a previewer built-in.

You can also use jquery and track your events in a specific list and go from there, a bit tricky but doable.